# What are the best practices for load select options via ajax in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I have a form contains select element like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Keyword</th>
        <td>{{input type="text" value=job.keyword}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Color</th>
        <td>{{view "select" content=colors optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content._id"
            value=job.colorID}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently, I use model hook in Route to load `colors` via ajax promise:

```
App.JobDetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                    job: Ember.$.getJSON("/service/job/" + params.jobId),
                    colors: Ember.$.getJSON("/service/color/")
                });
    }
});
```

But, I think the `colors` shouldn't be part of the model--It should belong to controller or view. 
Are there any practices that can gracefully load data in controller or view instead of model hook?

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't load data external data in an Ember controller or view, the route is the place to do so. You basically have two options:

- Use the model hook (why didn't you create models for Job and Color actually?)
- Use the [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) method like so:

  ```
  setupController: function(controller) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    this.store.findAll('color').then(function(colors) {
      this.set('colors', colors);
    }.bind(controller));
  },
  ```

The disadvantage of the second option is that Ember won't wait for the colors to load before it transitions to this page.

Comment: @Thormas Brus, Thanks for your reply. Currently, I do use the model hook to load job and colors. But when I need transit to JobDetailRoute, the hook will never invoked. Then I have to load the colors in the previous route/controller.Then I end up loading colors in every place that may transite to JobDetailRoute.For example, in job list, the colors data are useless in the list, but I have to load them because the next route need them to render a select element.
I think the other Routes/Controllers should'nt care about the colors. 
Please forgive my English, hope you can understand.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. This is something I bumped into as well. You could use link-to with an id instead of the model so that Ember will invoke the model hook again. Otherwise the second option that I listed is the way to go I think.

Comment: Also, I think it is the responsibility of the router to fetch all the data you wish to display, so even though the route is called JobDetailRoute it is still acceptable to fetch data from other models.

Comment: Thank you! Your 'link to id' is a good idea! This is the best solution I have met!

Comment: The second option can be optimized: Use some placeholder in the form before the colors loaded.

Comment: Sure, you might as well add the colors property to the controller then and give it a default value:)